# How to use localstorage in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to use local storage to be able to save user login details in a angularjs. How to use localstorage in angualrjs?
can you share sample code or tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://thejackalofjavascript.com/an-end-to-end-hybrid-app/) is a very good example of end-to-end app with angular.

This app use local-storage for saving the login 'token'.

Here is some ***sample from the code*** that use local-storage:

```
angular.module('bucketList.services', [])
.factory('API', function ($rootScope, $window) {

    $rootScope.setToken = function (token) {
        return $window.localStorage.token = token;
    }

    $rootScope.getToken = function () {
        return $window.localStorage.token;
    }

    $rootScope.isSessionActive = function () {
        return $window.localStorage.token ? true : false;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/fredricrylander/angular-webstorage provides a facility to use localStorage as default storage. and use session or memory when localStorage is unavailable. It uses storage defaults to ['local', 'session', 'memory'].

Sample code:

```
var x = $webStorage.get('someProp');
$webStorage.add('someProp',x);
$webStorage.remove('someProp');
```